# python3 my program will not work if the cmd is not above the other windows

Tags: python-3.6

```
import pyautogui
import time
start = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:\\Users\\dio\\Desktop\\BOT FUNZIONANTI\\'
                                       'helpdesk\\comandi\\bottoni\\email.png')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.moveTo(start)
time.sleep(5)
x1, y1 = pyautogui.position()
positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x1).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y1).rjust(4)

pyautogui.click(x=x1, y=y1)
print(x1)
print(y1)
```

this is my program
and I do not explain why if the cmd is above all other windows will work
if I activate the program and after i click on other windows ... (then it is no longer in the front of the screen will not work)

sorry for my english thanks to all